# On the fly MySQL balance

Tags: mysql

> Please excuse my English translation that makes by Google Translate

I need to solve the following in a MySQL query **without** php or another language:

In the “A” column I have a string value, in “B” and “C” column I have numerical values. The “D” column should equal `B - C`, as long as **the “A” column has the same value**. An example below:

```
A       B        C       D
Data1   10        2       8
Data1             2       6
Data2   50        2      48
Data2            10      38
```

@Critique, The real query

A=sim_items_djai_declaacancelar

B=sim_items_djai_cantidaddec

C=sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec

D=_varSaldo2d

Note: In the query, the calculation is only for the first part of UNION, where _varSaldo2d is 0

```
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
0 as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (_declaacancelar)
INNER JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
INNER JOIN opr_djai_estado USE INDEX (_destsimnitem) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar = opr_djai_estado._item
INNER JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_items AS sim_items_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = sim_items_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = sim_items_djai._oficializacion AND opr_djai_estado._item = sim_items_djai._item
INNER JOIN sim_lst_um USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
INNER JOIN opr_djai USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai_estado._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND opr_djai_estado._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
INNER JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
WHERE
(sim_caratula._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
and sim_caratula._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29')
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._itemacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn)
UNION
(SELECT
cmn_lst_clientes._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_desc,
cmn_lst_clientes_un._desc AS cmn_lst_clientes_un_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn AS sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion AS sim_caratula_oficializacion,
opr_djai_estado._fb AS opr_djai_estado_fb,
opr_djai_estado._fv AS opr_djai_estado_fv,
sim_items_djai_decla._item AS sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar,
opr_lst_djai_estados._descesAR as opr_lst_djai_estados_desc,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as sim_items_djai_cantidaddec,
sim_lst_um._descesAR as sim_lst_um_desc,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_destsimn,
null AS sim_items_djai_decla_oficializacion,
'' as sim_items_djai_decla_item,
0 as sim_items_djai_decla_cantidaddec,
sim_items_djai_decla._cantidaddec as _varSaldo2d
FROM
sim_items AS sim_items_djai_decla USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
LEFT JOIN sim_caratula USE INDEX (PRIMARY) ON sim_items_djai_decla._declaacancelar = sim_caratula._destsimn AND sim_caratula._destsim = 'SIMI'
LEFT JOIN sim_items ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = sim_items._declaacancelar AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = sim_items._itemacancelar
LEFT JOIN opr_djai ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai._oficializacion
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes._id
LEFT JOIN cmn_lst_clientes_un ON opr_djai._cliente = cmn_lst_clientes_un._cliente AND opr_djai._un = cmn_lst_clientes_un._un
LEFT JOIN opr_djai_estado ON sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn = opr_djai_estado._destsimn AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion = opr_djai_estado._oficializacion AND sim_items_djai_decla._item = opr_djai_estado._item
LEFT JOIN opr_lst_djai_estados ON opr_djai_estado._estado = opr_lst_djai_estados._id
LEFT JOIN sim_lst_um ON sim_items_djai_decla._unidaddec = sim_lst_um._id
WHERE
ISNULL(sim_items._declaacancelar)
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion >= '2015-12-22'
AND sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion <= '2016-04-29'
and opr_djai._cliente = '61'
GROUP BY
sim_items_djai_decla._destsimn,
sim_items_djai_decla._oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla._item)
ORDER BY
sim_items_djai_declaacancelar,
sim_caratula_oficializacion,
sim_items_djai_decla_itemacancelar
```

Answer (score 1):

**Critique**

Do not store the data that way.  Store it this way:

```
A       B        C       D
Data1   10        2       8
Data1   10        2       6
Data2   50        2      48
Data2   50       10      38
```

If you want to *display* it the other way, that is for an application to do.  Do not try to do it in SQL.

**How to do what you want**

It *is* possible in SQL, but it is ugly.  If you are starting with

```
A       B         C
Data1   10        2
Data1             2
Data2   50        2
Data2            10
```

Something like this should generate what you want.  (However, it will have a couple of extra columns.)

```
SELECT
        t.A,
        t.B,
        t.C,
        IF (t.A = @previous_A, @previous_B, t.B) - t.C AS D,
        @previous_A := t.A,
        @previous_B := t.B
    FROM table AS t
    JOIN ( SELECT @previous_A := '', @previous_B := 0 ) AS initialize
    ORDER BY t.A ASC, t.B DESC
```

You could use that as a subquery to throw away the extra columns.

Comment: Critique, I have added to question the actual query, thanks for your time